# Getting DSLR's drive information in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get my connected DSLR's drive information so that I can access the photos inside the SD card. I can't directly read from the SD card because of project requirements.

I tried using .NET's `DriveInfo` but it couldn't register my connected DSLR. Am I doing anything wrong?

Code:

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach(DriveInfo d in drives)
{
   if(d.Name == "D5100")
      Console.WriteLine("Camera found");
}
```

Edit: The results of the following code is that "C://" is found only. No other drives are detected.

Edit2: The connected DSLR seems to not be under any drives.
[image: DSLR Drive information]

Comment: http://stepsix.org/2010/03/31/an-intro-to-wia-windows-image-acquisition-in-c-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DriveInfo.GetDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) method gets only logical drives on your computer.

> Retrieves the drive names of all logical drives on a computer.

In my computer, it returns only `C:/`, `D:/` and `E:/`. Because of that reason, `d.Name` gives these type of information, not like `D5100`. There is a platform called Wia (Windows Image Acquisition) which can access images in cameras, webcams etc. Loot at [`this link`](http://itsmikebender.com/2009/08/using-c-sharp-and-wia-2-0-to-connect-to-an-imaging-device/).

Comment: Wow thanks! I was just reading about WIA before I saw your comment. Thanks again!